# Как использовать вложенные циклы for в kotlin?

Tags: алгоритм, kotlin, циклы

Как использовать, вложенные циклы `for` в kotlin, по kotlin'у мало информации  в интернете и на англоязычных сайтах, я студентка пытаюсь решать задачи leetCode, Когда смотрю, как другие решают задачи с помощью двойных циклов, я не могу понять их код, опытные товарищи поделитесь пожалуйста знанием.  Вот пример двойных циклов но как они работают не пойму.

Еще внутри цикла прибавлять, отнимать можно?

```kotlin
fun twoSum(nums: IntArray, target: Int): IntArray {
    val nums = arrayOf(2, 7, 11, 15);
    for (i in nums.indices) {
        for (j in i + 1 until nums.size) {
            if (nums[j] == target - nums[i]) {
                return intArrayOf(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution")
}
```

Comment: Откройте любую базовую книгу по алгоритмам и прочитайте. Тут совершенно не в языке дело, Вы явно самой базы не знаете.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить этот код мысленно, на бумажку выписывайте значения `i` и `j` и посмотрите, что получается. Если где-то застряли или, например, не понимаете как точно работает какая-то конструкция языка, то напишите об этом в вопросе, [дополнив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1287776/edit) его.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun twoSum(nums: IntArray, target: Int): IntArray {
    val nums = arrayOf(2, 7, 11, 15);
    // nums.indices -> генерирует массив индексов [0, 1, 2, 3] 
    // i итерируется по этому массиву 0, 1, 2, 3
    for (i in nums.indices) { 
        // i + 1 until nums.size -> создаёт диапазон (IntRange) от i+1 до размера nums
        // nums.size = 4 (4 элемента в массиве)
        // until -> создаёт диапазон, который не включает последнее значение
        // диапазон будет следующим [i + 1, i + 2, ... nums.size) (если конечно i всё ещё меньше nums.size)
        for (j in i + 1 until nums.size) { 
            // cравниваем nums[j] с target - nums[i]
            if (nums[j] == target - nums[i]) {
                return intArrayOf(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution")
}
```

Как этот алгоритм примерно выглядит:

- Итерация i = 0

  - Итерация j = 1

    - Сравниваем nums[1] == target - nums[0]
    - Сравниваем 7 == target - 2
    - Если условие сработало, то выход: возвращаем массив индексов [0, 1]
  - Итерация j = 2

    - Сравниваем nums[2] == target - nums[0]
    - Сравниваем 11 == target - 2
    - Если условие сработало, то выход: возвращаем массив индексов [0, 2]
  - Итерация j = 3

    - Сравниваем nums[3] == target - nums[0]
    - Сравниваем 15 == target - 2
    - Если условие сработало, то выход: возвращаем массив индексов [0, 3]
- Итерация i = 1

  - Итерация j = 2

    - Сравниваем nums[2] == target - nums[1]
    - Сравниваем 11 == target - 7
    - Если условие сработало, то выход: возвращаем массив индексов [1, 2]
  - Итерация j = 3

    - Сравниваем nums[3] == target - nums[1]
    - Сравниваем 15 == target - 7
    - Если условие сработало, то выход: возвращаем массив индексов [1, 3]
- Итерация i = 2

  - Итерация j = 3

    - Сравниваем nums[3] == target - nums[2]
    - Сравниваем 15 == target - 11
    - Если условие сработало, то выход: возвращаем массив индексов [2, 3]

Answer (score 1):

Прежде, чем запустить код, попробуем его прочитать и интерпретировать с помощью мысли:

Итак, есть массив размером 4:

```kotlin
val nums = arrayOf(2, 7, 11, 15);
```

Теперь посмотрим на этот цикл в цикле:

```kotlin
for (i in 0..3) {
    for (j in i..3) {
        // код
    }
}
```

- Заходим во внешний цикл, i = 0, запускаем внутренний цикл, j меняется от 0 до 3
- Следующий шаг внешнего цикла, i = 1, запускаем внутренний цикл, j меняется от 1 до 3
- Следующий шаг внешнего цикла, i = 2, запускаем внутренний цикл, j меняется от 2 до 3
- Следующий шаг внешнего цикла, i = 3, запускаем внутренний цикл, j меняется от 3 до 3
- Цикл завершается, так как дошли до последнего индекса 3.

А теперь запустим код, распечатаем `i` и `j` таким образом:

```kotlin
for (i in 0..3) {
    println("i = $i")
    for (j in i..3) {
        println("  j = $j")
    }
}
```

На выходе получаем:

```kotlin
i = 0
  j = 0
  j = 1
  j = 2
  j = 3
i = 1
  j = 1
  j = 2
  j = 3
i = 2
  j = 2
  j = 3
i = 3
  j = 3
```